# How do I select text between two "bookmarks" in Word VBA?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

Note: Originally I asked how to select text from a certain point downward, but I've got a solution for that:

```
Dim f As Word.Field
For Each f In ActiveDocument.Fields
    If f.Type = wdFieldAddin And f.Data = "BeginBody" Then
        f.Select
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdExtend
    End If
Next
```

Now, my question is how do I select the text between "BeginBody" and "EndBody"?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use two [bookmarks](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/add-or-delete-bookmarks-HP001226532.aspx). Name the start bookmark "start" and the end bookmark "end".
After that, the following code will select the complete text between those two.

```
Sub SelectTextBetweenBookmarks()

    Set rngStart = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Start").Range
    Set rngEnd = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("End").Range

    Range(rngStart.Start, rngEnd.End).Select

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn' know about bookmarks within word docs. I do get an error "sub or function not defined" on the line: "Range(rngStart.Start, rngEnd.End).Select" Could that have something todo with it being a doc/dot, and not docx/dotm? In spite of everyone here using 2007 or 2010, we do need every document to be a doc file for another program.

Comment: @Ernst Have you set up [those two bookmarks correctly](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijc48.png) as I said? I re-tested it again and it works

Comment: it does seem so, start is before end, and the names are correct, even if Word were case-sensitive.

Comment: I added in "ActiveDocument." before range, and now it works

Comment: Well, this is strange. It should also work without `ActiveDocument` since both arguments already refer to `ActiveDocument`. Hmm, which Office version do you use? Are multiple word files open?

Comment: 2010. I think I had multiple files open, but the macro is in a module in the one needing it, and that file was the active document.

Comment: @nixda: In Word, Range is a property of a number of different objects, including Document, but it is not a Global object. If you use it in the ThisDocument module of the document, it is interpreted as a property of the Document. Otherwise, you have to qualify it. The values rngStart.Start and rngEnd.End are just numbers that specify start and end points - the fact that you have specified rngStart and rngEnd does not provide any information about which Range object you are constraining.

Comment: @bibadia That's a difference to Excel VBA, right?

Comment: @nixda: Yes, the Range objects are completely different in the two applications. IN Excel you can do Debug.Print Range("A1", "A2").Cells.Count in an ordinary module and it will (I think) assume the active sheet.